# How does Protractor executes the function calls. (E2E AngularJS + Protractor + Jasmine)

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I am new to protractor and currently experimenting with an internal Angular JS application. In the below snippet of code, I am unable to understand on how Protractor is executing the statements and function calls. The behaviour seems weird OR I am doing something completely wrong. Appreciate all the help.

```
    describe('Describe Function', function() 
{

    it('Should return a value',function(){
        var IndexValue = ' ';

        var col_model = element.all(by.repeater('col in renderedColumns'));
        var row_model = element.all(by.repeater('row in renderedRows'));

        browser.get('URL');

        ptor = protractor.getInstance();

        var user = element(by.model('login.user_id_1'));
        user.sendKeys('demo');

        element(by.id('txtusername')).getAttribute('value').then(function(text) {
            console.log(text); // This line prints 'demo'
        });

        var pwd = element(by.model('login.password_1'));
        pwd.sendKeys('demo');

        var submit = element(by.className('login-submit'));
        submit.click();

        browser.driver.sleep(1000);

        var colCount = element.all(by.repeater('col in renderedColumns')).count(); 
        colCount.then(console.log) // This prints '80'

        var items = [];
        getArrayList();
        function getArrayList() // Function to capture all the content of the table in an array
        {
            console.log('Array List function started');
            colCount.then(function(Col_count){
                for(var i=0; i < Col_count; ++i){
                    var grid =  browser.findElement(by.repeater('col in renderedColumns').row(i));
                    grid.getText().then(function(gridValue){
                        items.push(gridValue.trim());
                        console.log('For loop')
                    });
                }
            });
           console.log('Array List function completed');
        }
        console.log(items); // This prints []
        getGridValue('Prospect');
        function getGridValue(name) 
        {

            console.log('Inside grid value');

        }

    });
});
```

When I execute the above code, even before the browser is invoked and the application is launched, first 4 lines (specified below) are printed on the console. What surprises me is the fact that point 1 and 3 are part of the function call which indeed is printing point 7. Looks like all the independent "console.log" are executed first and then the "console.log" associated with "element." statements are executed. Its really confusing. Plz let me know where am I going wrong. Thanks.

**OUTPUT ON THE CONSOLE**
1. Array List function started
2. []
3. Array List function completed
4. Inside grid value
5. demo
6. 80
7. For loop
For loop
For loop
For loop
.... so on until the loop ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first: well, protractor does, what you told it to do... You may read a bit about promises and async JavaScript.

I try to explain a bit, please understand, that explaining everything would take a lot of time.

Starting protractor calls your script (spec). The most lines you wrote before calling `getArrayList()` are function calls which return promises. This means, the function is called, and when ready, it's callback function gets called (e.g.: `then(...)`)

An example:

```
        var colCount = element.all(by.repeater('col in renderedColumns')).count(); 
        colCount.then(console.log) // This prints '80'
```

In this two lines you are searching the DOM for every element which can be located by `col in renderedColumns`, then, if ready, count them and return the value to its callback `then`, afterwards print it via `console.log`.

But all of this takes time, and this is the reason why `console.log('Array List function started');` gets printed before `colCount.then(console.log)`.

Hope I could help a bit, as mentioned before, you may read a bit about promises.